# How to set console for auto login in inittab of busybox?

Tags: linux, tty, console, busybox-init

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24) with busybox as `init`.

The kernel log is disabled in serial console without setting `console=` in kernel command line.  So is the logs from init scripts launched by `/etc/init.d/rcS`.

Now the `/etc/inittab` is set as follows,  and I want to enable the auto-login of root to the system.

```
# /etc/inittab
#
# Copyright (C) 2001 Erik Andersen <andersen@codepoet.org>
#
# Note: BusyBox init doesn't support runlevels.  The runlevels field is
# completely ignored by BusyBox init. If you want runlevels, use
# sysvinit.
#
# Format for each entry: <id>:<runlevels>:<action>:<process>
#
# id        == tty to run on, or empty for /dev/console
# runlevels == ignored
# action    == one of sysinit, respawn, askfirst, wait, and once
# process   == program to run

# now run any rc scripts
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS

# Put a getty on the serial port
##OK##::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 115200 vt100
ttyS0::respawn:-/bin/login -f root
#no login
#::respawn:-/bin/sh

# Stuff to do for the 3-finger salute
::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/reboot

# Stuff to do before rebooting
null::shutdown:/etc/init.d/rcK
null::shutdown:/bin/umount -a -r
null::shutdown:/sbin/swapoff -a
```

I set the line of `ttyS0::respawn:-/bin/login -f root` in the `/etc/inittab`, but I cannot see the login prompt in serial console.

So in this case of no valid console is set kernel command line, how to auto-login to the system on the correct serial console ?

Or is there a way to set the system console on the fly in user space (without using `getty -L`) ?

Answer (score 0):

With many searches in google and tests, I finally find an answer to the first question from this linke https://www.vjiot.net/typecho/index.php/archives/50/, here it comes.

In the `/etc/inittab`, use following line

```
ttyS0::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 115200 -n -l /bin/autologin
```

And created `/bin/autologin` as follows,

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/login -f root
```

With these changes, autologin of root is done!

Now, I still need to figure out the answer to the 2nd question: "How is the console being setup/used by init of busybox, is it possible to setup console on the fly in user space?"